# Ho to set line colors on a nvd3 parallel Coordinates chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, parallel-coordinates

I am using NVD3 to create a parallel coordinates diagram: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/parallelCoordinates.html

But it is not clear how to change the color for each of the dimensions?

```
nv.addGraph(function() {

    chart = nv.models.parallelCoordinates()
        .dimensions(["name", "attr1", "attr2", "attr3", "attr4"]);

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(array)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/parallelCoordinates.js), it looks like the colours are hard-coded to `d3.scale.category20c()`. So to change the colour, you would have to change the source.

Comment: `nv.utils.optionsFunc.bind` looks like it might be doing some magic? You might be able to specify colors there.